problems with keyboard shortcuts in lyx 2.4
im using arch with kde 6.1 and recently i noticed that some of my shortcuts are no longer available. for example i had the shortcut "alt+8" for "math-insert \cdot" but now it uses bookmark-save 8 instead, altough it is deleted.
in general the use of alt key was different because I remember that if i pressed the alt key once i than changed focus to the menu bar, and if i pressed 'f' I could open the file menu, now i have to press them together which is a problem since i cant use 'alt+f' as a shortcut for example.
here is my shortcut settings


I do not understand your question. In case it helps, note the following:

If you press Alt and release it, you access to the menu commands using the keyboard.
If you press Alt and press another characters such as M before releasing Alt, you are writing a shortcut.

